# How to detect Sphero collisions in Unity (for Android) using C#

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, sphero-api, sphero

I'm new using the Unity-Plugin for the Sphero API, that can be downloaded here:

https://github.com/orbotix/UNITY-PLUGIN

I understand the examples here, but I don't know how to detect when the Sphero collides? I want to play a sound in the Android app (made in Unity) when the Sphero detects a collision. I have read the official info for detecting collisions with Sphero here:

http://sdk.sphero.com/sdk-documentation/advanced-commands/

But I don't understand how to implement this using the official C# libraries providen by Sphero.

Please I need some guide to implement a Collision Detector using C# in Unity (for Android). Thanks in advance!